# Is switching my flourescent light fixures to LED fixures a DIY project?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

My house has a fluorescent light fixture that includes a ballast. I saw instructions [here](http://www.homepower.com/articles/home-efficiency/electricity/changing-fluorescent-tubes-leds) for changing it to a regular light fixture that I can use for LED bulbs instead. Is this a project that I should attempt on my own? Do I need to hire an electrician? I have switched numerous switches in my house so far, and I'm a decent learner, but I don't have vast amounts of electrical experience.

Comment: It depends entirely on you. It's DIY for some, and far better to hire an electrician for others. Telling which you are across the internet is difficult.

Comment: I'm assuming, since most fluorescent applications provide a decent amount of light, you'll be replacing these with larger LEDs.

Keep in mind many larger LEDs give off electromagnetic interference (EMI) more so than fluorescent. You don't generally notice issues with cell phones, WiFi etc. with the 60 - 80 watt equivalents. Start getting stuff that's bigger and you may notice issues. However, with just one, you're probably fine.

Just FYI: I've had this happen to multiple people who tried exterior high output LED flood lights, and can no longer open their garage door from 10 ft away.

Comment: Ah.  Thanks for the heads up.  These are actually small circular tubes. I have no idea why the previous owner installed it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fluorescent fixtures are fairly simple to work with. There are LED tube bulbs that will plug right into the system without touching the ballast, but these cost more and are less energy efficient. Upgrading your existing fixture to ballast-free LED's should be easy- mostly consisting of just removing and throwing away the old ballast and rerouting some wires. If your existing tubes are not T12 you would also have to change the tombstone connectors.

There is a better article to read here at [EarthLED](https://www.earthled.com/blogs/light-2-0-the-earthled-blog-led-lighting-news-tips-reviews/33135492-how-to-buy-t8-and-t12-led-fluorescent-replacement-tubes) that describes different fluorescent tube replacements and how to use them. Here is a brief excerpt from the article:

> The oldest but also least expensive and most widely installed option
>   is the ballast bypass or direct wire LED fluorescent replacement tube.
>   Instead of building expensive circuitry inside to enable the function
>   with a ballast, this option instead allows the user to bypass the
>   ballast entirely and run directly off of the line voltage at the
>   installation.